# Should questions with answers but majority downvotes be deleted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, low-quality-posts

Recently, I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682388/is-it-possible-to-harness-energy-from-kugelblitz-mergers) question on Physics SE. This was a case of myself not thinking things through before asking the question; in any case the question was not of high quality and subsequently (rightfully) received downvotes.

The question is one that is very hard to "edit" to become a high-quality question. It has been marked as "not suitable for the site" and "off-topic" (both of which I agree with, by the way). Thus, I am considering **deleting the question**; simply letting it staying here doesn't make the site better, and might encourage more low-quality questions.

However, the question also has an accepted answer and it has also been viewed 67 times (as of the current moment). I do not want the efforts of the contributors on the questions to be in vain.

Should I delete the question (for the good of the site) or keep the question (for the good of the contributors)?

Comment: Once a question was answered and has upvotes you cannot delete it anymore. Check [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) and scroll to *When can't I delete my own post?*. What you should do is to edit your question to become a better question and eventually re-opened, which is not an easy task, btw. Be careful not to change the context in a way the given answer wouldn't make sense anymore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone's clarification, Vickel has pointed out that you *can't* delete your question if you have a question that already has any of the following:

- An answer with any number of upvotes (including just 1)
- An accepted answer
- Multiple answers
- An answer with an awarded bounty
- At least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question

(These are paraphrased from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that))

So, instead, you should **try to improve your question**. This means you shouldn't try to:

- Change the content of a question to the point the existing answers doesn't make sense
- Change the question's title to the point the existing answers doesn't make sense
- Combination of the two above